How to maintain listening for shortcut keys when VS Code window loses focus/inactive
I want to listen for Shift+Alt+r shortcut in VS Code in order to execute a command. How can I make this shortcut key still available when the VS Code window is inactive?
keybindings.json:
[
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+r",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "run"
    }
]

task.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python RemoteTools.py",
            "dependsOn": [
                // "build"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": true
            }
        }
    ]
}


This is only effective when the window is activated. How to make it still available when it is not activated?

define the shortcut under the OS you are working with, and re-route it to VSCODE ? (So the answer would depend on info not shared in the question....)

you can't hook in the OS key handling from within VSC, use an OS program that hooks in the key processing and route the command to VSC by socket or semaphore or .....

As far as I know, VS Code windows don't listen for / receive keyboard events when they aren't focused. Depending on the OS and its keyboard-related systems, it might not even be possible for an application to do. You could look for ways to configure the OS / its keyboard system to pass certain keyboard events to the VS Code window. Ex. maybe AutoHotKey on Windows, or something similar.

Thanks for you answer. I guess it's the best way so far.
